# Jython & Bottle : SSL-enabled web server

Tags: python, ssl, web, jython, bottle

I have a web application (webservices) that combine Bottle web framework and Jython ... managed to run it on several web servers as supported on Bottle Documentation and all work fine. (such as Paste, Cherrypy, ..etc)

but, when i try to enable SSL on the web server .. all fails ! and seems that cause they use pyOpenSSL wrapper for that which is not compatible with Jython.

Is there a pyOpenSSL wrapper for Jython? or
Is there any available web server that can be combined with Jython and Bottle frame work and can support SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick look I didn't see a pyOpenSSL wrapper for Jython.  You could proxy your app thru a webserver such as apache or nginx and have that manage your SSL.  I have nginx handle my SSL for my cherrypy app.

```
#nginx.conf

server
{
   listen 443 default_server ssl;
   ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/mydomain.crt ;
   ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/myserver.key;

   #  etc
}
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule

hope this helps.

Andrew